# Array index out of range skipping function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, parse-platform

When I try to loop through the following code, the `self.returnImage(displayedPicture!, currentIteration: i, completion: self.printValue)` function should have the `currentIteration` of `i`, which should be equal to 0, however when the code is ran, it is not equal to i.

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.numberOfImages; i++) {
                    let displayedPicture = object["productImage\(i)"] as? PFFile
                    self.returnImage(displayedPicture!, currentIteration: i, completion: self.printValue)
                    var oldI = -1
                    print(object.objectId)
                    print("oldI \(oldI)")
                    print("i = \(i)")
                    print("Getting objects")
                    // self.productImages.append((object["productImage\(i)"] as? PFFile)!)
                    print("oldI = i")
                    oldI++
                }
```

This is what the console prints out

1. Success
2. On businessDetailsVC
3. Number of images 2
4. Number of objects Optional(1)
5. Optional("H1b7iUj4PS")
6. oldI -1
7. i = 0
8. Getting objects
9. oldI = i
10. Optional("H1b7iUj4PS")
11. oldI -1
12. i = 1
13. Getting objects
14. oldI = i
15. currentIteration = 1
16. Number Of Images Count = 2
17. ImageViewArray Count = 1
18. fatal error: Array index out of range
    (lldb)

This is the `returnImage` function. Its as if the function is late to being called because it retrieves data from the Parse backend, this is noticeable because the `prints` are called before the function is called even though its the opposite in the code.

```
func printValue(result: Bool) {
    print("result = \(result)")
}

func returnImage(pictureFile: PFFile, let currentIteration: Int, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void) {
    pictureFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completion(result: false)
        } else {
            if let data = imageData {
                print("currentIteration = \(currentIteration)")
                //var circleArray = Array<UIImageView>()
                //var y : CGFloat = 0.0
                //var i = 0
                self.imageViewArray.append(UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(self.screenWidth/2 - 120, self.screenHeight/2 - CGFloat(self.numberOfImages + 80), 120, 120)))
                print("Number Of Images Count = \(self.numberOfImages)")
                print("ImageViewArray Count = \(self.imageViewArray.count)")

                self.imageView = self.imageViewArray[currentIteration] // This is the line where the Array index out of range occurs

                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.imageView.tag = currentIteration
                self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)

                //self.imageView[i].frame = CGRectMake(self.screenWidth/2 - 120, self.screenHeight/2 - CGFloat(self.numberOfImages + 10), 60, 60)
                //self.imageView[i].image = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
                self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

            }
        }

        completion(result: true)
    })
}
```

This is the full code. The array index out of range error occurs on the line with `self.imageView = self.imageViewArray[currentIteration]`

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class BusinessDetailsVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var businessTitle: String = ""

let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()

let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

var numberOfImages: Int = 0

var nameOfImage: [String] = [String]()

var productImages: [PFFile] = [PFFile]()

var downloadedImage: UIImage = UIImage()

var imageViewArray = Array<UIImageView>()
var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

//var displayedPicture: [PFObject] = [PFObject]()
//var imageView = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("On businessDetailsVC")

    let query = PFQuery(className: "C_h0usYnpEqL")

    print("Number of images \(numberOfImages)")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if objects! == objects! {
            print("Number of objects \(objects?.count)")
            for object in objects! {
                for (var i = 0; i < self.numberOfImages; i++) {
                    let displayedPicture = object["productImage\(i)"] as? PFFile
                    self.returnImage(displayedPicture!, currentIteration: i, completion: self.printValue)
                    var oldI = -1
                    print(object.objectId)
                    print("oldI \(oldI)")
                    print("i = \(i)")
                    print("Getting objects")
                    // self.productImages.append((object["productImage\(i)"] as? PFFile)!)
                    print("oldI = i")
                    oldI++
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

func printValue(result: Bool) {
    print("result = \(result)")
}

func returnImage(pictureFile: PFFile, let currentIteration: Int, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void) {
    pictureFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completion(result: false)
        } else {
            if let data = imageData {
                print("currentIteration = \(currentIteration)")
                //var circleArray = Array<UIImageView>()
                //var y : CGFloat = 0.0
                //var i = 0
                self.imageViewArray.append(UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(self.screenWidth/2 - 120, self.screenHeight/2 - CGFloat(self.numberOfImages + 80), 120, 120)))
                print("Number Of Images Count = \(self.numberOfImages)")
                print("ImageViewArray Count = \(self.imageViewArray.count)")

                self.imageView = self.imageViewArray[currentIteration] // This is the line where the Array index out of range occurs

                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.imageView.tag = currentIteration
                self.view.addSubview(self.imageView)

                //self.imageView[i].frame = CGRectMake(self.screenWidth/2 - 120, self.screenHeight/2 - CGFloat(self.numberOfImages + 10), 60, 60)
                //self.imageView[i].image = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width / 2
                self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true

            }
        }

        completion(result: true)
    })
}


  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

This is the backend where the object is stored, with two image files being retrieved
[image: This is the backend where the object is stored, with two image files being retrieved]

Answer (score 0):

As per your current logic, try to add ImageView with below code,

```
self.imageViewArray.append(UIImageView(frame:CGRectZero))
```

Because if error occurred, you will have less number of images in array for next iteration.
e.g. If error occurred in iteration 3 then, for next iteration 4, you will only 3 image if iteration 4 succeed.

Comment: that only changed the position of the UIImageView, it did not change whether the array had an index out of range or not